# How to JOIN three tables in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I played with JOIN last night with linking two tables which worked great, however I need to generate a CSV file so need data from three different tables and was wondering if this was correct? It needs to link them all up by invoice number which is invoice in this case:

SQL:

```
SELECT * 
        FROM invoices i
        JOIN customers c
        JOIN invoice_items p
        ON c.invoice = i.invoice
        ON p.invoice = i.invoice
        WHERE i.invoice = c.invoice
        AND i.invoice = p.invoice
        ORDER BY i.invoice
```

Comment: The conditions on field `invoice` in the `WHERE` clause are not needed, they duplicate the conditions in the `ON` clauses. `ON` is part of the `JOIN` clause. Put each `ON` after the `JOIN` it describes (`... invoices i JOIN customers c ON c.invoice = i.invoice JOIN invoice_items p ON p.invoice = i.invoice ...`. Find more information in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Although it's been solved, I think the problem (incorrect syntax) and the solution (repair the syntax) are not likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
$query = "SELECT i.* 
         FROM invoices as i 
         JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = i.invoice 
         JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = i.invoice 
         ORDER BY i.invoice";
```

instead of

```
$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM invoices i
        JOIN customers c
        JOIN invoice_items p
        ON c.invoice = i.invoice
        ON p.invoice = i.invoice
        WHERE i.invoice = c.invoice
        AND i.invoice = p.invoice
        ORDER BY i.invoice";
```

If you use just `JOIN` keyword than it will work like `INNER JOIN` otherwise you have to define the join type. Example: `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Thanks mate, im passing the invoiceID from ajax, should i replace = i.invoice with ".$id." ?

Comment: just ".$id." or need to apply c.".$id." i.".$id." ? thanks for your help

Comment: what is your field name?

Comment: setting as $id = $_POST['invoice'];

Comment: Actually dont worry, i want to get them all dont know why i was passing lol